# java две эквивалентные строки выводят разный результат

Tags: java, строки

Суть программы: из текстового файла извлечь слова и поместить в хеш таблицу.
Затем пользователь вводит какое нибудь слово и программа проверяет наличие или отсутствие.
Возникла интересная проблема:
Если я заношу слово в переменную при записи в хеш таблицу (s=word) то программа выводит правильный результат, а если строку с клавиатуры написать, или задать явно (hashMap.containsValue("что")) то программа не работает. Почему? Ведь все три строки эквивалентны, везде слово "Что".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
             
 HashMapImpl<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMapImpl<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "windows-1251");
       System.out.print("Введите слово для проверки: ");
        String num = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print(num);
 File f = new File("text1.txt");
 final int length = (int) f.length();
 
 String s="";
 
 if (length != 0) {
 char[] cbuf = new char[length];
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),"windows-1251");
 final int read = isr.read(cbuf); 
 String EXAMPLE_TEST = new String(cbuf, 0, read);
 // System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST); 
 isr.close();

 Pattern pattern =
                Pattern.compile("\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS 
                        | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
        SortedSet<String> words = new TreeSet<>();

        while (matcher.find())
            words.add(matcher.group().toLowerCase());

       for (String word : words)
            System.out.println("word = " + word);
     
        int n=0;
            for (String word : words)
            {hashMap.put(n, word);
            n++;
            s=word;}
            
   System.out.println(s);
   System.out.println(num);
     
 

    }
   System.out.println(s.equals(num));
 
System.out.println("Hashmap has value at null:"+hashMap.containsValue(s));

System.out.println("Hashmap has value at null:"+hashMap.containsValue(num));

System.out.println("Hashmap has value at null:"+hashMap.containsValue("что"));
 }
```

Comment: `(hashMap.containsValue("что"))` и `везде слово "Что"` - `что` и `Что` - разные слова

Comment: Ошибся, везде слово «что» но легче от этого не стало.

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас банальная проблема с кодировками (Win1251<->Utf8).

Comment: Трудно сказать без `HashMapImpl`

Answer (score 1):

Вы посмотрели, что у вас выводит `System.out.print(num)`?
У меня, к примеру, в этом месте распечатывается `С‡С‚Рѕ`. Разумеется, такой строки в вашем хэш-мапе нет.

Причина в том, что у меня консоль eclipse настроена принимать вход в кодировке utf-8. Если вы поменяете кодировку для сканера входного потока `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8");`, то всё заработает. У меня заработало.